# C++: Get and list all the files from directory that user writes

Tags: c++, list, file, directory, get

I am new here. I am working on a small program for binary packing files but I don't know how to make a function that would read and list all the files, with different names and extensions, inside a folder that user writtes.

```
string folder;
cout << "Input folder name: ";
getline (cin, folder);
```

So after that command, function suppose to use the "folder" and the current directory location to for that folder and read and list all the files inside it.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` to go through all files in a given directory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    const std::filesystem::path path{ "C:\\temp" };
    for (auto const& dir_entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator{ path })
        std::cout << dir_entry << '\n';
}
```

To get the filename only (without the path), use:

```
    std::cout << dir_entry.path().filename() << '\n';
```

Comment: This is a great comment; not that great of an answer.

Comment: I tried that but get many errors:

error: 'filesystem' in namespace 'std' does not name a type - 
error: 'std::filesystem' has not been declared - 
error: expected ')' before '{' token - 
error: 'path' was not declared in this scope - 
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token . I use Codeblocks 20.03

Comment: `-std=c++17` needs to be in your compile command.

Comment: Nevermind. It was a bug in mingw. I installed MSYS2 and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @YukiXXL glad it worked. Would you kindly accept the answer if it helped?

Comment: Yes. Just had to find how to. it took me time :) Should be accepted. Thank you once again.

Comment: Forgot to ask, is there a way to list filenames only, without the whole path?

Comment: @YukiXXL - please see an update in my answer.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you very much.